# Linux графическая оболочка и пакетный менеджер удалились

Tags: linux, elementary-os

Скачал сегодня программу Synaptic, так как не мог установить программу из за проблем с пакетным менеджером. Программа показала что у меня 13 пакетов не работают и их нужно удалить 32 обновить. Я согласился и после установки обновлений, он выдал ошибку что не мог удалить пару пакетов. После чего попал трей и нижнее окно с программами . Заставка осталась. Попробовав обновить пакеты через apt-get запросы, и не получив результата прошел на перезагрузку. Ну и собственно открылся терминальный вид. Папки на месте все нормально. Найдя информацию в интернете попробовал команду "install elementary-desktop. После сообщения что такого пакета нет, попробовал обновить пакетный менеджер и апгрейдить его. Не помогло,  посмотрел source list нашел в интернете содержание данного файла. (Решил в ручную откатить систему таким образом). Изменил файл но это не помогло. При попытке update upgrade команд пишет. Failed to fetch (ссылка на указанный репозиторий) temporary failure resolving ppa.launchpad.net. Гугл выдал что нужна команда remove purge source файла, затем fix и якобы все. Мне не помогло. Сделал autoremove, удалилось ещё пару пакетов. Фикс и обновление так же не помогли. Все делалось через супер пользователя. Если кто знает что делать подскажите пожалуйста. Не хотелось бы переустанавливать систему. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы вводили команды, не понимая их предназначения и игнорировали предупреждения (удаление пакетов). `и не получив результата прошел на перезагрузку` - перезагрузка в Linux очень редко когда требуется и редко когда помогает. Слава богу, в Linux все обложено логами. Что бы понять что вы там наделали, выложите `/var/log/apt/history.log` и дату начала эксперимента, чтобы понять откуда смотреть ваши действия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильное решение: сначала разобраться с сетью (resolv.conf, интерфейсы), затем установить один из DM (kde/plasma, gnome, mate, cinnamon, тысячи их). Тут чуть ли не каждый шаг может заслуживать отдельного вопроса.

Быстрое (как мне кажется в данном случае) решение: забэкапить данные и переустановить систему.

Comment: Вопрос решон уже. Спасибо большое за помошь. Сообщество все таки таксичное в ру))

Comment: Как решили проблему?

Comment: как вы и предлогали. Переустановил систему. Так как мой пакетный менеджер не работал как следует. я не мог просто установить удаленные пакеты и установить графическую оболочку. Пришлось ставить систему.